# $\lambda-z-e^{-z}=0$ has one solution in the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $\lambda > 1$ , want to show that the equation $$\lambda-z-e^{-z}=0$$ has exactly one solution in the right half plane $\{z:Re(z)>0\}$. Moreover, the solution must be real.
I tried to use Rouche's theorem on $g(z)=\lambda - z$ and $f(z)=e^{-z}$ to get that the number of zeros of $f+g$ and the number of zeros of $g(z)$ is the same, and since $g(z)$ has only one solution then the equation about must also have one solution the problem is I don't know how to choose the correct curve $\gamma$ such that this will work.
for the second part I used the IVT to show that $\lambda -x-e^{-x}$ has a zero in  $(0,\lambda)$ to conclude that the solution is real. is this acceptable? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you use Roche's theorem?  Don't you need $|f(z)| < |g(z)|$ for say $z = \lambda$.

Comment: @muzzlator I took a small circle with center $\lambda$ and the inequality you wrote should be true for all values on (not in) this circle, and this is that case.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yeah that looks like it works

Comment: Rouche is a good idea. But if you apply it to a small circle, how does this apply to the whole half-plane?

Comment: @julien I was thinking using part two i.e the real case we established that the equation has a zero in the right half plane, now lets assume we have another zero in the right half plane and take a circle containing both zeros to get a contradictoin, and conclude that there is exactly one solution. the problem I'm facing now is that I can't get the inequality of  Rouche's theorem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**A hint.**

If $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$ and $\lambda - z - e^{-z} = 0$ then

$$
|\lambda - z| = e^{-\operatorname{Re} z} < 1.
$$

In other words, if the equation has any solutions in the right half-plane then they lie in the open disc $|z-\lambda|<1$.

Comment: so if I take $\gamma$ to be the circle $|\lambda-z|=1$ then we have $|f(z)|=e^{-Re(z)}<1=|\lambda-z|=|g(z)|$, Thus, by Rouche's theorem $g$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros in this circle which is 1.

Comment: @i.a.m You're welcome.

Comment: wait, is the question asking us to prove there is only one solution which happens to be in right half plane OR that there exists only 1 solution in right half plane (and possible some solution in left half plane)?

Comment: @AlphaRomeo, the equation has infinitely-many solutions, and exactly one of those is in the right half-plane.

Comment: Can you please explain why you say infinitely-many solutions in left half plane? If z is purely real then I plotted and checked it can have only 1 solution. How to analyze when z is not purely real?

Comment: @AlphaRomeo, I gave a sketch of the analysis for a related equation, $1 + w - e^w = 0$, [in an answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588246/5531). (Note that that is just the equation from this question with $\lambda = 1$ and $w = -z$.) Most of the arguments in my answer there can be modified to work on the equation here. In particular, the argument using the Hadamard factorization theorem can be applied directly to show that this equation has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @AlphaRomeo, an alternative answer is that the equation in this question can be solved exactly in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and an analysis of the branches of the W function leads to the conclusion that there are infinitely many roots.